# Join Table, Do not show values when there is matches between two tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join, where-clause

I have one procedure where I have to join two tables:
First Table (General gen): FirstName, LastName, IssueStateCode
This is a general table that contains all information about user.
Second Table (Information inf):  ID, IssueState, Effective Date.
This table is modified by Admin. When there is any values (statecode) in inf.IssueState column and it matches with gen.IssueStateCode I do not show those results in stored procedure. This is for printing issue. When there is matches I dont want to print the results because this states is suspended from printing.

For example:
First Table (General gen): FirstName, LastName, IssueStateCode: Thomas, Parkey, CO; Elizabeth, Both, LA

Second Table (Information inf):  ID, IssueState, Effective Date: 1, CO, 205-01-01

In this case, my stored procedure should show all information about Elizabeth. But not about Thomas because his StateCode is in the second table.

I created stored procedure and joined these tables ( i have to join them based on IssueStateCode):

```
 left join dbo.Information inf on gen.IssueStateCode = inf.IssueState
```

in the WHERE clause I tried to use the following statement: 
WHERE gen.IssueStateCode <> inf.IssueState

This statement doesn't work. It displays zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` clause you want is:

```
WHERE inf.IssueState IS NULL
```

Your version is clever, although it is wrong.  When there is no match, `inf.IssueState` is NULL.  The `<>` operator returns `NULL` when either or both arguments are `NULL`.  And, `NULL` is treated as false, so all the rows get filtered out.